# Two projects using the same Django database. Who should create the tables?

Tags: django-models, django-database

I have two Django projects that need to use the same postgres database.

I created the database in one of the projects -- no problems;
I just created the second project. It will need access to tables in the database. It will also need some additional tables that only it will access.

Two questions:

1. In the second project, I am getting the 'unapplied migrations' message from the main app. How do I safely get rid of this? I don't want the second project changing the parts of the database that were created by the first app. However, I don't want necessary Django setup to not be done (is there any)?
2. Suppose I want to create a table used only by the second project. Should I do it in the second project and migrate it? Or should I do it in the first project to prevent the second project 'messing' with the database?

Many thanks.